# Why does the User Button on my Nucleo-G474RE board only influence my code if the PWM of the LED is active (STM32CubeIDE)?

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, stm32cubeide

I am trying to build a state machine and want to switch from state 1 to state 2 if the User Button on my board was pressed. However, this only works if the LED - which is controlled by a PWM on Timer 2 Channel 1 - is currently on. Otherwise, the LED switches off and unless I hit the Reset Button, nothing more happens.

For this, I configured PC13 (which is the Pin that, according to the schematic, is connected to the blue button) as GPIO_Input and gave it the user label BLUE_BUTTON. Under private variables, I defined a variable blueButtonHasBeenPressed as a uint8_t. My while loop looks like this:

```
    while (1)
    {
        blueButtonHasBeenPressed = HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(BLUE_BUTTON_GPIO_Port, BLUE_BUTTON_Pin);
        switch(state){
            case 0:
                [some statement that makes state = 1]
                                break;
            case 1:
                if(blueButtonHasBeenPressed == 1){
                    state = 2;
                }
                break;
        }
        switch(state){
            case 2:
                TIM2->ARR = 399;
                TIM2->CCR1 = 199;
                break;
            case 1:
                TIM2->ARR = 2999;
                TIM2->CCR1 = 1499;
                break;
            case 0:
                TIM2->CCR1 = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
```

With serial wire viewer, I found that a two is being written to the state variable and that the two registers are successfully manipulated. However, the LED does nothing. Does anybody have an idea what the problem could be or how I could solve this/work around this?

Comment: Just to rule out basics first: is bounce taken care of?

Comment: Your code never changes `state` from 2 to anything else. Once it's set to 2, it's forever 2. It never enters the first switch anymore, so it ignores button presses.

Answer (score 0):

Your `state=2` locks the system up: there is no path for `state` to change its value from 2 anymore:

0. Initial `state=0` (reasonable assumption on my part)
1. In the loop, you read button value. If it's 1, make the `state=2`. (switch 1)
2. If the `state=2`, set timer configs to certain value. (switch 2)
3. End of loop, new loop starts. `state=2`
4. Button level is read, but the first switch is never entered, so the `state` stays at 2 and button level is never used.
5. The second switch writes the same timer configs that are already in the timer.
6. Go to 3.

Comment: But how does this explain that I do not see the behaviour being in state 2 would make me expect. And why does it work if I press the blue button at the rifght time?

Comment: Depends on what you expect to see in state 2. Also, what does it mean it works if you press it at the right time? What time? What happens? If you keep randomly pressing it, it sometimes does something? You speak in half sentences. Add a paragraph of text to the question. Why the LED does nothing has nothing to do with the code you presented. It could be a separate issue, could be in timer or GPIO code. Your description of what and how exactly goes wrong is too incomplete to say anything specific other than your code locks in state=2 without any way to leave state=2.

Comment: As already explained in my question, when I press the button while the LED is on (which is directly connected to the PWM on Timer 2 being active), it displays the behavior that we'd expect in state 2: the LED blinking fast. When I press the button while the LED is off (PWM = inactive), the LED stays off although the PWM period and pulse are adjusted correctly

Comment: state 0 is a weird state, because apart from initial state being zero, your state actually never becomes zero. If the state is 0, the first switch immediately makes it 1. In other words, LED off is also an impossible state of your machine, unless there is some bug. In other words, your state machine is broken like this: `state=0` never happens (immediately turned into 1), `state=2` locks in `state=2` forever. There is no path that a button press can turn LED off in the first place. I would say, your entire state machine is broken. It's easier to rewrite the code you presented from scratch

Comment: Also, regarding your sporadic button-does-something that you never properly explained, I asked about bounce under your question, and you never replied. Is the button debounced? Otherwise all sorts of random stuff can happen.

Comment: Debouncing is nonsense in this case in my opinion. I want it to recognise the press as such as soon as I press. I do not want to have to hold the button for some time

Comment: @codingCode in that case I advice to read about what a bounce and debounce actually is (it's not exactly what you think). Make sure you eliminate bounce before returning to this, otherwise no button will ever work well for you (every time you press non-debounced button, MCU detects 1-5 presses)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have ARR preload switched on (i.e. if you have TIMx_CR1.ARPE==0), [changing ARR to value smaller than CNT](http://efton.sk/STM32/gotcha/g41.html) makes CNT to count up to the maximum value, which in case of TIM2 is 0xFFFF'FFFF. As you can see LED blink, you probably run timer at low clock and/or some prescaler, so counting up to 0xFFFF'FFFF probably takes longer than you are ready to wait.

Set ARPE; or clear CNT upon ARR change, by direct write or by forcing Update e.g. by setting TIMx_EGR.UG.

JW

Comment: interestingly, switching *on* the preload has the desired effect. Now, however, the new period and pulse are applied only after the reset value is reached...

Comment: So basically the behaviour of the next pulse is not predictable? Wow, that is a huge problem! What I have tried now was to disable the preload bit and to clear CNT in the register. Now, the LED blinks once for a good bit longer before going into the right rythm

Comment: What seems to be working best is to leave the bit on disable and to generate an update event by setting the UG bit of the Tim2_EGR register upon changing the state. This is not an ideal solution because the led lights up once after that (which not even writing the pin to zero changes) but it is definetely better than before. Thank you!